# Wordpress save_post_[post_type] hook only when creating a new post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I want to do actions only when a new post added, not updated

My code:

```
add_action( 'save_post_news', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 10, 3 );
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
        return;
    }

    if ( get_post($post_id)->post_status != 'publish' ){
        return;
    }

    if($update) return; //Not working

    do smth...
```

I found some same questions here, but they don't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

use the [`publish_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/) hook:

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {    
   //Do Stuff
    $email = 'email@example.com';
    $subject = 'New Post';
    $message = 'New Post Added: ' . get_the_title($post_id); 
    
    //Send Email
    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message );  
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

Comment: In my project code is correct. I made mistake only in this question. Your code also doesn't work. This construction: if($update) {return;} make the whole code non-working.

Comment: I also tried funcion save_post whith condition if ( get_post($post_id)->post_type != 'news' ){return;}. Same behaviour